# Java 8 get the HashMap values count

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

As known to all, you can count *elements* in `map` as below:

```
map.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getValue() > 0 ).count(); // get map elements size which contain values > 0
```

But what I'm trying to do is counting the element `x` **values**.

Is there a way to count the elements **values** in the `map` ?

Comment: `map.entrySet().stream().reduce(0,(sum,x)-> sum+x.getValue());` or `map.entrySet().stream().mapToLong(x -> x.getValue()).sum();`?

Comment: Contrary to your claim, the example code you present does not count keys.

Comment: @kichik yes Thanks, that's what I need.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it count elements plus filtering them which required elements above `0` value.

Comment: can you add an example with input and output that makes a bit clear

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've edit my question to be more clear

Comment: `Map.size()`? `Map.values().size()`? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user207421 whatever I got my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` for that or `mapToInt()` and `sum()`. You extract a stream of values you want with `mapToInt()` and then add them all up using `sum()`.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    map.put("a", 12);
    map.put("b", 3);
    map.put("c", 24);
    System.out.println(map.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getValue() > 0).mapToInt(x -> x.getValue()).sum());
  }
}
```

Comment: Except computing a sum, as this does, is quite a different thing from *counting*, as the OP requested.  But maybe this really is what they wanted, as they seemed to say in comments.  I'm pretty confused at the moment as to what is actually being asked.

Comment: Thank you, we can also use method reference instead `mapToInt(Map.Entry::getValue).sum()`